# Sum the contents of a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, coercion

Beginning JavaScript learner here...

I'm working through Adrian Neumann's [Simple Programming Problems](https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html) and my question is about number 5 in the elementary exercises.

> Write a program that asks the user for a number n and prints the sum of the numbers 1 to n... such that only multiples of 3 and 5 are considered.

Here is my code as it currently stands...

```
var myArray = [];
var mySum = 0;

var userNum = prompt("What is your number? "); {
    for (var i = userNum; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
            mySum += myArray.push(i);
        } 
    }
}
console.log(mySum);
```

This produces the result `28` which is not correct. When I comment out the `mySum` statement and print the array for the input of `17` I get `[15, 12, 10, 9, 6, 3]` which looks correct.

I would be interested in tips on why the `mySum` statement doesn't provide the expected result. I would also be interested in any tips to make the code more efficient. Many thanks!

**Edit**
For anyone interested, here's the code I settled on for being best for my purpose and current level:

```
var mySum = 0;

var userNum = prompt("What is your number? ");
for (var i = userNum; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
        mySum += +i; // type coercion with unary operator
    } 
}
console.log(mySum);
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Why array? `mySum += i;` or if you want: `mySum += i; myArray.push(i);` or `myArray.push(i);` and afterwards reduce the array: `sum = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});`

Comment: Array.prototype.push returns the new length of the array, not the value you provide, which is why your sum is incorrect.

Comment: Note the outer `{ ... }` are not necessary.

Comment: There is a difference between array.push and array.pop methods. Its good to know what the code will do before writing. As you are using Array, I suggest you to take a look at following link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.

Comment: I think you don't need an array to solve this problem

Comment: What happens with 15 or 30? Are these values counted once or twice?

Comment: @tigger My understanding of the logical `OR` is that if either are true, the code simply continues. Therefore, in the case of `15`, since the first condition is true the second will simply be ignored. Can someone confirm this to be true?

Comment: @zeitchef yep, that's right. 15 or 30 will act the same as 5 or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since myArray.push(i) does not return the number you pushed but the current length of the array, your sum is not what you expect.

Instead use `mySum += i;`

or if you want to still use the array to later process/console.log the separate numbers:

```
 mySum += i; 
 myArray.push(i);
```

or just `myArray.push(i);` and afterwards reduce the array:

```
sum = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

Here I also cast the string you get when you prompt to a number and remove the wrapping `{ }` which are not necessary

```js
var myArray = [];
var mySum = 0;

var userNum = prompt("What is your number? "); 
for (var i = +userNum; i > 0; i--) {
  if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
    mySum += i;
    myArray.push(i);
  } 
}
console.log(mySum,myArray);
```

Alternative using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - it is likely overkill in your case but I include it for completeness' sake:

```js
var myArray = [];
var mySum = 0;

var userNum = prompt("What is your number? "); 
for (var i = +userNum; i > 0; i--) {
  if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 3 === 0) {
    myArray.push(i);
  } 
}
mySum = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});


console.log(mySum, myArray);
```

Comment: This looks like a delightful answer, but a little more advanced than my current level of understanding. What are the inherent advantages to the reduce method? (I'm a total beginner as stated before). Thanks.

Comment: The first example will do what you need. The reduce is an elegant way to return some manipulation on an array: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - possibly a bit of an overkill in your case since you loop anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the docs for [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). It says: "Returns the new length property of the object upon which the method was called."

That means that every time you call `mySum += myArray.push(i)`, you are saying `mySum += myArray.length` (after having pushed `i`).

Instead you should just add `i` to `mySum`:

```
mySum += i
```

instead of

```
mySum += myArray.push(i)
```

In terms of better code, I agree with mplungjan - Array.reduce would be a good one to use here.

**Edit**: actually, since you're not starting with an array but a number, in this case a for loop is probably the quickest and cleanest way to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following optimized approach using "negative" `while` loop:

```
var userNum = prompt("What is your number? "),
    mySum = 0;

while (userNum--) {
    if (userNum && (userNum % 5 === 0 || userNum % 3 === 0)) {
        mySum += userNum;
    }
}
console.log(mySum);  // 60
```

Answer (score 0):

A "just math" (no loop) option. This is better for larger numbers than a loop.

```
var a = parseInt(prompt('What is your number?'));
var five = Math.floor(a / 5);
var three = Math.floor(a / 3);
// if values like 15 are counted twice, remove 'both'
// otherwise this is required to remove the doubling up.
var both = Math.floor(a / 15);

var result = (multiple(five) * 5)
    result += (multiple(three) * 3);
    // remove these results if "15" is counted only once
    result -= (multiple(both) * 15);

// this is the tricky party.
function multiple(x) {
    return (((x + 1) / 2) * x);
}

console.log('result:['+ result +']');
console.log('a:['+ a +'] 3:['+ three +'], 5:['+ five +'], 15:['+ both +']');
```

NOTE: No checks to confirm if the input is a number.